# Define enum representation type in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I would like to know, is there any posibility in `C#` to change `default (integer)` representation of `enum` to something with less weight like `char`.

Many of you will ask me why I want to do it? Answer is simple:

I have to work at huge, huge `Array`. 
My PC allow me to allocate memory for array of integer with 540 000 000 elements (2048 * 2048 * 128). Everyone know `integer` needs aroud 4 times more memory than `Char`.

`Char` representation give me `2 000 000 000` elements to manipulate.

Much easier in programming masive algorithms is to work at `Enum` than `char` but if the change of representation isn't possible I will have to work on charracters.

Comment: Actually `char` is a UTF-16 code unit and hence two bytes large. You want `byte`.

Comment: There may be room to use an optimised data structure. If most of your data has a fixed default value, you can use sparse data structures that will only "remember" non-default values.

Comment: @oleksii On the topic of optimizing, if there are, say, only <= 16 alternatives, cramming multiple values into each byte is also viable. And unlike sparse structures, it helps with random/hard-to-compress data too and doesn't really slow down any operations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can change the type of an enum but not to `char`. For your `byte` can work well as it's 1 byte type. Check [enum (C# reference) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type **except char**. The default underlying type of enumeration elements is int. To declare an enum of another integral type, such as byte, **use a colon after the identifier followed by the type**, as shown in the following example.

```
enum Days : byte {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

> The approved types for an enum are `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`.

Comment: `as it's also 1 byte type` a `char` is actually 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can specify the underlying type

```
public enum MyEnum : byte
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
enum MyEnum : byte
{
    ...
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify underlying type of enum. From [enum (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any
>   integral type except char. The default underlying type of enumeration
>   elements is int. To declare an enum of another integral type, such as
>   byte, use a colon after the identifier followed by the type

```
public enum YourEnum : byte
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) shows you how.

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any
>   integral type except char. The default underlying type of enumeration
>   elements is int. To declare an enum of another integral type, such as
>   byte, use a colon after the identifier followed by the type, as shown
>   in the following example.
>
> ```
> enum Days : byte {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
> ```

Note well that in C# `char` is two bytes wide. You presumably mean to use `byte`. But as you can see from the documentation, the compiler would have rejected your attempt to use `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the enum of another integral type such as byte like this:

Public enum MyEnum : byte {}

Comment: This is not inheritance.

Comment: I've replaced the "inherit" since its not the right meaning in this case even the syntax might be deceptive